# How to pass the params:id in the url explicitly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a User model and Posts model. I want to display the posts belonging to each user,
via a URL say http://localhost:3000/my_posts/1" but Rails is reporting error saying
that no matching route exits for
    http://localhost:3000/my_posts/1.

Rails looks at the complete url : "http://localhost:3000/my_posts/1" as a route , but my
intend is like "http://localhost:3000/my_posts/" should be taken as url route and '1' should  be taken has the params:id in this case it represents the User_id.
I have the route match
      "/my_posts" => "user#view_posts".

The action routine view_posts of user is working fine when triggered through
      "http://localhost:3000/users/1"
here in takes 1 as params id and /user as route.
And also i'm able to display that particular user's posts in the "/user" route by
rendering the partial
    <% render 'view_posts %>

I'm Using Rails version 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
match "/my_posts/:id", :to => "user#view_posts"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
map.connect 'my_posts', :controller => ..., :action => ...
```

Comment: Hi Nikita I'm using rails version 3 and i have the following route set :-    match "/my_posts" => "user#view_posts". But my question is how do I pass a params id to that controller's action.

Comment: You don't. You just call '/my_posts?param1=123&param2=abc' and _param1_ and _param2_ will be passed into _params_ hash. You don't specify _param1_ and _param2_ in route declaration.